# Iterate on OrientRecord object

Tags: iteration, increment, python-3.6, orientdb

I am trying to increment twice in a loop and print the OrientRecord Objects using Python.
Following is my code -

```
for items in iteritems:
    x = items.oRecordData
    print (x['attribute1'])
    y=(next(items)).oRecordData #Here is the error
    print (y['attribute2'])
```

Here, iteritems is a list of OrientRecord objects. I have to print attributes of two consecutive objects in one loop.

I am getting the following error -

> TypeError: 'OrientRecord' object is not an iterator

Answer (score 1):

Try using a different approach to it:

```
for i in range(0,len(iteritems),2):
    x = iteritems[i].oRecordData
    print (x['attribute1'])
    y = iteritems[i+1].oRecordData
    print (y['attribute2'])
```

The [range()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) function will start from 0 and iterate by 2 steps.
However, this will work properly only if the total amount (range) of records is an even number, otherwise it'll return:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

I hope this helps.